# ¿Cómo instalar el módulo 'tabulate' a Python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x

En la terminal coloque esto para descargarlo:

**pip install tabulate**

Luego veo esto:

**Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in c:\users\danny paolo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.8.9)**

Luego imprimo mi código y me sale esto:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'**

Al parecer el modulo tabulate esta en un archivo de ANACONDA3, ahora como hago para que tabulate funcione en mi código?

Comment: Seria bueno que pongas el código de como lo importas, ya que puedes tener un error allí. Igual te digo como debes hacerlo ```from tabulate import tabulate```

Comment: Coloque: **from tabulate import tabulate**, pero me sale nuevamente **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'**

Comment: Verifica si no tienes un archivo llamado así en tu proyecto

Comment: Parece que tienes probablemente al menos dos versiones de Python instaladas, ya que parece que el pip que usas para instalar el paquete no es de la misma versión que python que usas luego para ejecutarlo. Lo mejor para asegurarte de que lo instalas en la misma versión en que luego lo ejecutarás es ejecutarlo con `python -m pip install tabulate`